# Equals() contract for .NET Dictionary / IDictionary vs equals() contract for Java Map

Tags: java, .net, collections, immutability, equality

Nostalgic for `Collections.unmodifiableMap()`, I've been implementing a read-only `IDictionary` wrapper based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002/does-c-have-a-way-of-giving-me-an-immutable-dictionary), and my unit test quickly ran into a problem:

```
Assert.AreEqual (backingDictionary, readOnlyDictionary);
```

fails, even though the key-value pairs match. I played around a little more, and it looks like at least (thank Simonyi)

```
Assert.AreEquals (backingDictionary, new Dictionary<..> { /* same contents */ });
```

does pass.

I took a quick look through the [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/xfhwa508(v=VS.80).aspx) and [`IDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/s4ys34ea(v=VS.80).aspx) documentation, and to my surprise I couldn't find any equivalent of the Java [`Map`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) contract that two `Maps` with equal `entrySet()s` must be equal. (The docs say that `Dictionary` -- **not** `IDictionary` -- overrides `Equals()`, but don't say what that override does.)

So it looks like key-value equality in C# is a property of the `Dictionary` concrete class, not of the `IDictionary` interface. Is this right? Is it generally true of the whole `System.Collections` framework?

If so, I'd be interested to read some discussion of why MS chose that approach -- and also of what the preferred way would be to check for equality of collection contents in C#.

And finally, I wouldn't mind a pointer to a well-tested `ReadOnlyDictionary` implementation. :)

---

**ETA:** To be clear, I'm **not** looking for suggestions on how to test my implementation -- that's relatively trivial. I'm looking for guidance on *what contract those tests should enforce.* And why.

---

**ETA:** Folks, I *know* `IDictionary` is an interface, and I *know* interfaces can't implement methods. It's the same in Java. Nevertheless, the Java `Map` interface documents an expectation of [certain behavior](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) from the `equals()` method. Surely there must be .NET interfaces that do things like this, even if the collection interfaces aren't among them.

Comment: There's a ReadOnlyDictionary<K,V> in the MS.Internal.Utility namespace in the WindowsBase assembly. It doesn't override Equals.

Comment: I'm writing a Mono app for iOS, but that's an interesting data point. Are two `MS.Internal.Utility.ReadOnlyDictionaries` with the same contents equal to each other?

Comment: Noted for later readers: (1) the `Algorithms` class in [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) provides  `ReadOnly` methods for wrapping collections (including dictionaries) as read-only. (2) LINQ's [SequenceEqual()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) works on ordered collections (including dictionaries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For later readers, here's what I've been told / been able to figure out:

1. The contract for .NET collections,
   unlike Java collections, doesn't
   include any specific behavior for
   `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()`.
2. LINQ `Enumerable.SequenceEqual()` 
   extension method will work for
   ordered collections, including
   dictionaries -- which present as
   `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair>`;
   `KeyValuePair` is a struct, and its
   `Equals` method [uses reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009394/c-value-type-equals-method-why-does-the-compiler-use-reflection)
   to compare the contents.
3. `Enumerable` provides other extension
   methods that can be used to cobble
   together a content equality check, such
   as `Union()` and `Intersect()`.

I'm coming around to the idea that, convenient as the Java methods are, they might not be the best idea if we're talking about mutable collections, and about the typical implicit `equals()` semantics -- that two `equal` objects are interchangeable. .NET doesn't provide very good support for immutable collections, but the open-source [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) library does.

Comment: Java, unlike .NET, has no concept of an "equality comparer".  When mutable types are used as entities, reference equality makes sense; when used as values which won't change while they're in a dictionary, value equality makes sense.  In most cases where something that knows nothing about a class will be comparing instances, it's better to err on the side of reporting things unequal, which .NET's default reference equality does.  In cases where code storing things in a dictionary knows that value equality makes more sense, it can specify an equality comparer that tests that.

Comment: Since Java doesn't have an equality comparer type, the only way types can make their values usable as dictionary keys is to override their equality-related methods to use value equality, and hope that instances which are being used as entities don't get stored into a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding equals is normally only done with classes which have a degree of value semantics (e.g. `string`). Reference equality is what people are more often concerned about with most reference types and a good default, especially in cases which can be less than clear (are two dictionaries with exactly the same key-value-pairs but different equality-comparers [and hence adding the same extra key-value-pair could make them now different] equal or not?) or where value-equality is not going to be frequently looked for.

After all, you are looking for a case where two different types are considered equal. An equality override would probably still fail you.

All the more so as you can always create your own equality comparer quickly enough:

```
public class SimpleDictEqualityComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    // We can do a better job if we use a more precise type than IDictionary and use
    // the comparer of the dictionary too.
    public bool Equals(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return true;
        if(ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        if(x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;
        TValue testVal = default(TValue);
        foreach(TKey key in x.Keys)
            if(!y.TryGetValue(key, out testVal) || !Equals(testVal, x[key]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 0x15051505;
            foreach(TKey key in dict.Keys)
            {
                var value = dict[key];
                var valueHash = value == null ? 0 : value.GetHashCode();
                hash ^= ((key.GetHashCode() << 16 | key.GetHashCode() >> 16) ^ valueHash);
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

That wouldn't serve all possible cases where one wants to compare dictionaries, but then, that was my point.

Filling up the BCL with "probably what they mean" equality methods would be a nuisance, not a help.

Comment: The equality-comparer adds an extra wrinkle that Java doesn't have, I admit.

Comment: @David, Java has some way of defining an external definition of equivalence between objects though, surely?

Comment: Yes and no. There's `Comparator`, and if your implementation of `Comparator.compareTo(a, b)` returns 0, `a` and `b` are supposed to be equal. Usually nobody discovers this until they construct a `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` (the default sorted implementations) and members start falling out of it due to a bad `Comparator` implementation, though. There isn't really anything like `IEqualityComparer` in the standard library -- collections just use `equals()`. (Except, as noted, `TreeMap/TreeSet`, which take a shortcut.)

Comment: @Jon: A small nitpick: Your `GetHashCode` method is dependent on the ordering of `dict.Keys`, and that ordering isn't guaranteed in any way. Two `IDictionary<K,V>` instances containing the same set of key-value pairs could, in theory, produce different hashcodes even though they compare as equal.

Comment: Ah, I take it then that Comparator doesn't support the sort of weak ordering where things could sort in the same position, but not be equal. I think I prefer the split of `IEqualityComparer`/`IComparer` (and the comparable `IEquatable`/`IComparable` for defining a default within a class) but what you describe would still do the trick most of the time. You had me in a panic, as I don't look at Java much but I was shocked at the idea it might not have any such equivalence provider, and that I might not have noticed!

Comment: @LukeH. You are entirely correct. Editing to replace with an order-agnostic method.

Comment: Suggestions: Why enumerate just the keys and do a `x[key]` lookup? Why not loop the dictionary itself? See Luke's answer. Also you would want to avoid boxing for value types.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() from NUnit.  Assert.AreEqual() is really not meant for collections. http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4

Comment: That's interesting. It looks like `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` does actually pass. -- No, I take that back, it doesn't. But it ought to. Maybe I actually have a bug.

Comment: Certainly CollectionAssert is what you want.

Comment: Can you comment on why CollectionAssert is not suitable?

Answer (score 1):

```
public sealed class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue>
    : EqualityComparer<IDictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    public override bool Equals(
        IDictionary<TKey, TValue> x, IDictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
        if ((x == null) || (y == null)) return false;
        if (x.Count != y.Count) return false;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in x)
        {
            TValue yValue;
            if (!y.TryGetValue(kvp.Key, out yValue)) return false;
            if (!kvp.Value.Equals(yValue)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 1299763;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> kvp in obj)
            {
                int keyHash = kvp.Key.GetHashCode();
                if (keyHash == 0) keyHash = 937;

                int valueHash = kvp.Value.GetHashCode();
                if (valueHash == 0) valueHash = 318907;

                hash += (keyHash * valueHash);
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor suggestion: Use `EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default.Equals(kvp.Value, yValue)` to avoid null exception in the `Equals` method. Similarly in `GetHashCode` method, you would need to check for `kvp.Value == null`.

Answer (score 1):

> So it looks like key-value equality in
>   C# is a property of the Dictionary
>   concrete class, not of the IDictionary
>   interface. Is this right? Is it
>   generally true of the whole
>   System.Collections framework?
>
> If so, I'd be interested to read some
>   discussion of why MS chose that
>   approach

I think it is quite simple - `IDictionary` is an interface and interfaces can't have any implementations and in .NET world equality of two objects is defined through `Equals` method. So it is just impossible to override `Equals` for the IDictionary interface to allow it possesing "key-value equality".

Answer (score 0):

you made a big mistake in your original post. You talked about the `Equals()` method in the `IDictionary` interface. That's the point!

Equals() is a virtual method of `System.Object` that classes can override. Interfaces **don't implement methods** at all. Instead, instances of interfaces are reference types, thus inheriting from `System.Object` and *potentially* declaring an override of `Equals()`.

Now the point... `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>` does **not** override Equals. You said you implemented your IDictionary your own way, and reasonably overriden Equals, but look at your own code

```
Assert.AreEqual (backingDictionary, readOnlyDictionary);
```

This method is basically implemented as `return backingDictionary.Equals(readOnlyDictionary)` and again here is the point.

Basic Equals() method returns false if two objects are instances of different classes, you cannot control that. Otherwise, if the two objects are of the same type, each member is compared via reflection (just members, not properties) using the `Equals()` approach instead of `==` (which is what the manual calls "value compare" instead of "reference compare")

So for first, I would not be surprised if `Assert.AreEqual (readOnlyDictionary,backingDictionary);` succeeds, because it would trigger a user-defined Equals method.

I have no doubts that approaches by other users in this thread work, but I just wanted to explain you what was the mistake in your original approach. Surely Microsoft would have better implemented an Equals method that compares the current instance to any other IDictionary instance, but, again, that would have gone outside the scope of the Dictionary class, which is a public stand-alone class and is not meant to be the only public available implementation of IDictionary. For example, when you define an interface, a factory and a protected class that implements it in a library, you might want to compare the class against other instances of the base interface rather than of the class itself which is not public.

I hope to have been of help to you.
Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I spoke imprecisely. It's the same situation in Java -- `equals()` is a method on `Object`. However, the Java `Map` interface "overrides" `equals()` (not really; it just re-declares it) to _document_ the _expectation_ that it return true for any two `Map` implementations with the same key->value mappings. It's what those expectations are in the .NET collections, and why, that I want to know.

Comment: Got it now... you might need to read into .NET developers' minds :(

Comment: @djechelon: If two references are used to encapsulate identity, they should compare equal if and only if they identify the same object.  Two unshared references which encapsulate state *and do not encapsulate identity* should compare equal if they encapsulate the same state.  Unfortunately, neither .NET nor Java makes any distinction between references that should encapsulate identity and those that should not--a limitation which not complicates equality testing and cloning among other things, but is the underlying cuase of many mutability-related bugs.