# Linq Distinct not returning expected values

Tags: c#, .net, linq, equality

I am trying to get a list of distinct items from a custom collection, however the comparison seems to be getting ignored as I keep getting duplicates appearing in my list. I have debugged the code and I can clearly see that the values in the list that I am comparing are equal...

NOTE: The Id and Id2 values are strings

Custom Comparer:

```
public class UpsellSimpleComparer : IEqualityComparer<UpsellProduct>
{
    public bool Equals(UpsellProduct x, UpsellProduct y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id && x.Id2 == y.Id2;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(UpsellProduct obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
var upsellProducts = (Settings.SelectedSeatingPageGuids.Contains(CurrentItem.ID.ToString())) ?
                              GetAOSUpsellProducts(selectedProductIds) : GetGeneralUpsellProducts(selectedProductIds);

// we use a special comparer here so that same items are not included
var comparer = new UpsellSimpleComparer();
return upsellProducts.Distinct(comparer);
```

Comment: Use `string.Equals()` to check string value equality

Comment: @shree.pat18 Why? (Note language tag is C#, not Java)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Agreed, but I prefer doing that. Nothing wrong with `==` in C#.

Comment: @shree.pat18 making this change did not affect the result, isn't `==` operator equivalent to `.Equals()`?

Comment: @MatthewPigram Yes, which is why this was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely `UpsellProduct` has default implementation of `GetHashCode` that returns unique value for each instance of reference type.

To fix - either implement one correctly in `UpsellProduct` or in comparer.

```
public class UpsellSimpleComparer : IEqualityComparer<UpsellProduct>
{
   public bool Equals(UpsellProduct x, UpsellProduct y)
   {
       return x.Id == y.Id && x.Id2 == y.Id2;
   }

   // sample, correct GetHashCode is a bit more complex
   public int GetHashCode(UpsellProduct obj)
   {
      return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Id2.GetHashCode();
   }
```

}

Note for better code to compute combined `GetHashCode` check [Concise way to combine field hashcodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065251/concise-way-to-combine-field-hashcodes) and [Is it possible to combine hash codes for private members to generate a new hash code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079192/is-it-possible-to-combine-hash-codes-for-private-members-to-generate-a-new-hash)

Comment: this was the problem, why is the default implementation of `GetHashCode()` unique for each instance of the same type?

Comment: @MatthewPigram because by default 2 unique instances of the same type are not "Equal" - so having `GetHashCode` to return different value matches behavior of "Equal" and let Dictionary quickly check hash codes to rule out non-equal objects (note that this is the only reason `GetHashCode` exists - so it better be useful for it).

Comment: Does this mean then that if I had 2 instances with exactly the same data, checking for equality would result in a false result? Or does the default hashcode get generated using class members like your solution above?

Comment: @MatthewPigram yes, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17573720/should-an-override-of-equals-on-a-reference-type-always-mean-value-equality, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009394/c-sharp-value-type-equals-method-why-does-the-compiler-use-reflection, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123512/why-anonymous-types-equals-implementation-compares-fields  (and links there) - value/anonymous types have Equals/GetHashCode pair generated so it take into account all field, reference types don't.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GetHashCode()` doesn't return the same values even two `UpsellProduct` instances are consider equals by your `Equals()` method.

Use something like this to reflect the same logic instead.

```
public int GetHashCode(UpsellProduct obj)
{
    return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Id2.GetHashCode();
}
```