# Struct with one decimal field and defautl equals

Tags: c#, decimal

How does default `Equals()` work on struct like this one:

```
public struct Decim
{
    decimal x;

    public Decim (decimal x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

`new Decim(-0m).Equals (new Decim(0m));` return true, why? if it doing bitwise comparsion, I thought decimal uses special bit to indicate sign

also `new Decim(5.00m).Equals (new Decim(5.000000m));` reports true, but when I do `new Decim(5.00m).ToString()` and `new Decim(5.000000m)).ToString()` it produces different values. How does to string knows it?

Comment: This is two questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: [Can anyone explain this strange behavior with signed floats in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508945/can-anyone-explain-this-strange-behavior-with-signed-floats-in-c)

In default Equals:

```
if (CanCompareBits(this)) // will return false for decimal
{
    return FastEqualsCheck(a, obj);
}
```

So defauklt equals will use reflection for decimal field. For double it will do fastEqualsCheck.

Answer (score 0):

This is the decompiled version of Equals from mscorlib:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    RuntimeType type = (RuntimeType) base.GetType();
    RuntimeType type2 = (RuntimeType) obj.GetType();
    if (type2 != type)
    {
        return false;
    }
    object a = this;
    if (CanCompareBits(this))
    {
        return FastEqualsCheck(a, obj);
    }
    FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
    {
        object obj3 = ((RtFieldInfo) fields[i]).InternalGetValue(a, false);
        object obj4 = ((RtFieldInfo) fields[i]).InternalGetValue(obj, false);
        if (obj3 == null)
        {
            if (obj4 != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!obj3.Equals(obj4))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can understand what the Equals does.

source: [Original StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009394/c-sharp-value-type-equals-method-why-does-the-compiler-use-reflection)

Comment: So, why I does not enter CanCompareBits for decimal, but when I change field to double, it enters? How Does CanCompareBits work? Cannot see, because its extern.